# Multiple Days CVRP: Choose from Multiple Demand Matrices

Tags: or-tools

I would like to make the model choose a demand matrix. For example one  matrix would look like this for three days. Each line is one day:

```
[[0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

But a day-delivery can be substituted by a delivery on another day, so another matrix could be this:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1]]
```

Now I want the model to decide if its is better to use the first matrix or the second matrix. You can't pick the first and third line of the first matrix and the second line from the second. That would be forbidden.

I thought maybe it is possible to define a dimension for each demand matrix, but only one of these must be fulfilled.

Thank you in advance.
Thomas

Comment: Why not running the routing solver twice (for each demand model) and choose the solution with the best objective ?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It should work. I thought there would be an alternative way, which uses less computing power, when there is a big number of matrices.